# I think the tag "english-to-japanese" should be dropped

Tags: discussion

I am sorry, I am kind of, you know with little smile, [what is the tag "english-to-japanese" here for????](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42440/seo%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Blocation%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-what-does-location-mean-within-a-seo-plugin) No I mean, seriously.When I asked the linked question, I chose the tag "word-choice" because I had known for a long time the **very translation** ( I am not sure how far it can go ) is not allowed. But if, if you allow, or made ( I hadn't known that there had been such a tag ) such a tag, **wouldn't that mean, LITERALLY, the very translation whichever it is long or short, is O.K????**

Thank you for your assistance...

Comment: Should I take this issue seriously or with "relaxed manner" regarding this...thank you..

Answer (score 3):

[english-to-japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-to-japanese) is usually used for trying to find a Japanese equivalent of an English word or expression. From the tag wiki excerpt:

> 英和訳. Finding a Japanese equivalent of an English word or expression, especially when a straight translation to Japanese might have different connotations from the original English phrase.

In your question, you ask how to translate the English word "location" (used in some technical context) into Japanese, so I think this tag fits your question perfectly.

(The existence of the tag doesn't make any related question on-topic. Translation requests from/to English to/from Japanese are off-topic.)

---

[word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is used for asking about differences between seemingly interchangeable Japanese words. (For example, the difference between ただ and 無料.) Again, the tag wiki excerpt:

> 使い分け. The differences between two or more words or phrases and how to select the best one for a given situation.

I guess [word-choice](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is a possible tag, but I thought you aren't really looking for answers that explain the difference between ロケーション and 場所 (which you as a native speaker are probably well aware of).

Comment: I am sorry to use this phrase, -- I hope someday I can figure out what you are trying to **do** 100%. -- Sorry.